Proof of Equivalent Propositions of the Axiom of Choice.
My native language is Chinese, so I use a translation machine.
How can I prove that the following two propositions are equivalent?
(1) $\mathbf{Proposition}$:
Given $\{S_{i}\}_{i\in I}$ is a family of sets and $\forall i\in I(I\neq\emptyset),S_{i}\neq\emptyset$,then $\prod_{i\in I}S_{i}=\\
\{f:I\rightarrow \bigcup_{i\in I}S_{i}\,|\,\forall i\in I,f(i)\in S_{i} \}\neq\emptyset.$
(2) $\mathbf{Axiom\,of\,choice}$: $\forall X,\exists f:P(X)/ \{ {\emptyset} \} \rightarrow X,\forall S\in P(X)/ \{ {\emptyset} \},f(S)\in S.$
I've completed the proof of $(2) \Longrightarrow (1)$.That is given $\{ S_{i} \}_{i\in I}$ is a family of sets,let $X=\bigcup_{i\in I}S_{i}$ to complete the proof.
But I don't know how to prove $(1)\Longrightarrow (2)$.
Given $X\neq\emptyset$, I don't know how to strictly construct the set family $\{ S_{i} \}_{i\in I}$ that will satisfy $\forall i\in I(I\neq\emptyset),S_{i}\neq\emptyset$.
I try to number all non-empty subsets of $X$ using index set $I$,but I quickly discovered a problem. This numbering method is not unique. Does this mean that we need to assume that the axiom of choice is true?
If we can number all non-empty subsets of $X$ using index set $I$ without assuming the axiom of choice, then how can I write it down for sure?
Hope you can understand my question and I will thank you very much.

Here's a direct proof:
Suppose $(1)$ and let $X$ be any set.
If $X=\emptyset$, then $f=\emptyset$ exists and satisfies the required condition.
Instead, if $X \neq \emptyset$, let $I=P(X)$ \ $\{\emptyset\}$, and let $S$ be the identity function on $I$.
Now, by $(1)$, $\displaystyle \prod_{i \in I} S_{i} \neq \emptyset$; thus, there exists a function $f:I \to \displaystyle\bigcup_{i \in I}  S_i $, such that $f(i) \in S_{i}$ for every $i \in I$. But by the definition of $I$ and $S$, this just means that there exists a function $f:P(X)$ \ $\{\emptyset\} \to X$ such that $f(s)\in s $ for every $s \in P(X)$ \ $\{\emptyset\}$.
$\square$
(Note that $\displaystyle \bigcup_{i \in I}S_{i} = \bigcup [P(X)$ \ $\{\emptyset\}]=X)$.

Thank you very much for your explanation! I have two small questions about the proof you wrote: 1. Why do we need to define this”$S$ be the identity function on $I$”? 2. Does the $f:I\rightarrow\bigcup_{i\in I} { S_{i} }$you wrote have the same meaning as the definition $f:I\rightarrow\bigcup_{i\in I} S_{i}$ I gave? I mean $\bigcup_{i\in I} { S_{i} }= \bigcup_{i\in I}S_{i}={ a, | , \exists i\in I,a\in S_{i} }$.

@BaoYuBo 1. We define $S$ in this way to turn $I$, which is just $P(X)$ \ ${\emptyset}$, into an indexed family of sets (namely ${S_{i}}{i \in I}$). This allows us to use $(1)$. 2. That's a mistake on my part, I'll fix it: I mixed up the notations $\displaystyle \bigcup{i \in I} S_{i}$ and $\bigcup {S_{i}}_{i \in I}$.

For my first question, do you mean that the so-called family of sets ${ S_{i} }{i\in I}$ means a function $g:I\rightarrow { S{i} },i\mapsto S_{i}$, so ${ s }_{s\in I}$ means a function $S:I\rightarrow P(X)/ { \emptyset },s\mapsto s$?

@BaoYuBo Not exactly. $A={S_{i}}_{i \in I}$ just means $A={S(i):i \in I}$. Note that for this to make sense, both $I$ and the function $S$ must be defined, with the domain of $S$ including $I$. Then $A$ is said to be indexed by the function $S$, and $I$ is said to be the index set.

I think I understand what you mean, by “$S$ be the identity function on $I$”, it represents function $S:P(X)/{ \emptyset } \rightarrow P(X)/ { \emptyset },s\mapsto S(s)=s$ , which in fact represents ${ S_{s} }_{s\in P(X)/ { \emptyset } } = { S(s),|, s\in P(X)/{ \emptyset } }$
Hope I didn't understand it wrong.

Sorry there is something wrong with my formula code, I don't know why there is a period "." in the last formula. So I keep deleting comments in order to edit them again.

It's fine. Your understanding is correct too.

Your solved my question, thank you very much!

Assume (1) and suppose (2) isn't true. Then there exists a set $\;X\neq\emptyset\;$ such that for any
$$\;f:P(X)\setminus\emptyset\to X\;,\;\;\text{we get that}\;\;P(S)\notin S\;\text{for some}\;\;S\in P(X)\setminus\emptyset$$
But this means that the product as you defined it in your question
$$\prod_{R\in P(X)\setminus\emptyset} R$$
as you defined it in your question has to be empty since for $\;S\in P(X)\setminus\emptyset\;$ we have that $\;f(S)\notin S\;$ for any function $\;f\;$ as defined...!

Thank you for your explanation. I want to confirm, are you using proof by contradiction?
